# Overlapping Views Manager in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I have a Backbone + RequireJS application with root views that are rendered upon page load. In addition I have a bunch of views that are opened on top of the root views or on top of each other.

The idea is that each view triggers a change, adding a fragment to the URL. Multiple views can be rendered on top of each other with certain parameters defined by the view that launched them.

How do I achieve a structure that passes required data to the view that is rendered and that browser history stays aware of the changes and switches views accordingly?

In practice for example, if I press the back button, the front most view is removed and the underlying view is activated with all the data that it was initialized with.

EDIT: 
What I need:

1. Router that listens for hash value changes and maintains a stack for views that are rendered
2. A way to initiate and render a view from inside another view with certain parameters

USE CASE: Every time a user opens a new view on top of an existing view, the router stores the new view in the stack. With a dedicated "close" button or pressing the browser's "back" button the router automatically removes the top view from the stack and the previous view is exposed.

What kind of a structure should I build to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: Are you using backbone router? Did you read the documentation for backbone router and the fact that it supports HTML5 pushstate?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Backbone router and with that I'm able to manage the history data in the browser. The problem is more about combining communication between views and routing at the same time. For instance a situation where I have multiple views on top of each other and each one is initiated by the previous view. Then user presses the back button and the front most view closes and reveals the previous view in its original state.